# SP2016 - Content Web Search Part - all Tasks in all SiteCollections

Tags: 2016, content-query-web-part

I am new to SHarepoint and new to this plattform - so please excuse in case this is a not  wise question :-)

We have an intranet on the basis of sharepoint. Each department has its own site collection and each collaboration room or project also has its own site collection.
So there is not really a hirarchy in it.

In each Sitecollection there might be a tasklist and we have the requirement that each user get an overview of its own tasks. I tried to use the web search part, but I only got those tasks which are in the sitecollection I put the webpart on.
Is there an (easy) possibility to search over all sitecollection and display the tasks?

Thanks for your help

kind regards 
PK

Answer (score 0):

Content Query Web Part displays content from a single site collection. You can use Content Search Web Part in order to show content across site collections. This link shows how to configure it.

[Configure a Content Search Web Part in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-a-content-search-web-part-in-sharepoint-0dc16de1-dbe4-462b-babb-bf8338c36c9a)